# How to split modules into chunks when using Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-5

What I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
build/
    - index.html
    - scripts/
        - entry.min.js
        - libs/
            - react.min.js
            - react-dom.min.js
            - ...
```

I've surfed the internet and what I found is mostly just how to use `webpack.optimizations` in a basic way. It doesn't really show me how to split all the libraries and put them in a different file while keeping their name easily readable.